# Eclipse auto completition issue

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

I have installed the **eclipse kepler** edition and I want when extending a class or start to override a method to pop with options but it doesn't although it pops things when referring to an object's function.

I tried to see the options `preferences->java->editor->advanced` and checked all of them but nothing still the same.Any advices?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

go to, Window >> Preferences >> Java >> Editor >> Content Assist >> Auto activation triggers for java, and enter `.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` , this will trigger the auto activation for class names, methods, etc...